# One Date Picker for Insert and View Data without Refreshing Page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have made a Single Page to Insert and View Data and Only One DatePicker is used, page is divided in two divs one for form Insertion and other for $result Retrieval (Fetching Data).

My Question is, whatever the Date I select on the Date Picker I want to load the data of that specific date into the $result Div without Refreshing the whole Page. 
A Few lines from my code to understand:

> ```
> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" >//div for date
>             <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>......">
>                         <input type="text" " name="date"     id="datepicker"value="<?php echo $formattedDate; ?>">
>                     </div>
> <div class="col-md-12">
>                 //div for form insertion
> </div>
> <div class="col-md-12">
>                 //div for data Retrieval
>                     <?php
>                     foreach($AmountReceivedonDate->result() as $row)
>                     {?><br>
>                             <h4><?php echo $row->amount ?>-00</h4>
>                                 <h4><?php echo $row->name ?></h4>
>                     <?php }
>                     ?>
> </div>
> ```

Now How can I Get Latest data (as per Given Date)

> foreach($AmountReceivedonDate->result() as $row)

without Refresing Page..
Is it Possible??

Comment: do you want save this date in database?

Comment: the records are saved in database I want to fetch the data of selected Date

Comment: i think you should data send using ajax and fetch by same request